# Time gap between multiple Session a user had on a video id

Tags: r

Hi everyone I am new to stack overflow community. Any help from you guys would be highly appreciated. I want to calculate the time gap between multiple sessions a  user had on a particular video. For example in the attached image i have information about user id, video id, date, start time and end time. Each row is called a session, now in this file I want to get the no of sessions an idividual had on a particular video_id(so a user id and video_id would be a unique combination). Just want to get the no of sessions an individual had on each video he played and also the time gap between each session on that video.

```
    UserId                                 Video_id Date        Start       End
    88A5F59B-2A3F-45C8-8072-7CEF623C59AD    516223  6/17/2017   9:58:44     10:09:54
    f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65    516379  6/17/2017   10:27:15    10:27:19
    f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65    516379  6/17/2017   10:25:49    10:26:21
    f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65    516379  6/17/2017   10:10:30    10:10:30
    f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65    516379  6/17/2017   9:48:17     9:48:24
    bd9299dc-462a-4fde-aed1-ed8cfd9b437f    516221  6/17/2017   17:44:34    17:44:34
    f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65    516379  6/17/2017   9:34:05     9:46:57
    f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65    516379  6/17/2017   9:27:33     9:27:33
    625fbd55-50bc-40c8-a321-3fc5d6545148    515531  6/17/2017   7:25:27     7:25:39
    421c6815-9a7c-432c-9f07-2b19d973628c    514625  6/17/2017   20:53:27    20:53:27
    b3467b1c-f0d1-4330-95ab-d1a6efe88044    487491  6/17/2017   20:25:31    21:08:01
    5155a544-0ee8-4376-ad9f-d839ce691aa7    459908  6/17/2017   16:29:49    16:50:25
    4db1ef03-90f4-4c23-9e73-df3f78f59507    514625  6/17/2017   17:41:03    17:41:03
    4db1ef03-90f4-4c23-9e73-df3f78f59507    514625  6/17/2017   17:28:04    17:36:58
    3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f    515531  6/17/2017   14:50:47    14:51:28
    3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f    515531  6/17/2017   14:47:44    14:47:47
    3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f    515531  6/17/2017   14:45:53    14:47:01
    43fc3478-d3b0-4f96-a6a1-4e23fa5e075c    515889  6/17/2017   23:47:41    23:49:26
    b4f442bc-6e15-4757-850f-3d1444be74c5    515461  6/17/2017   23:57:53    23:57:53
    b4f442bc-6e15-4757-850f-3d1444be74c5    515531  6/17/2017   23:56:33    23:56:33
    a07898f2-2fba-4406-b3f4-8cc9e9f51ecf    515531  6/17/2017   23:46:37    23:53:45
    cb222c84-c32c-40f5-9fab-e4ce5be0985e    515889  6/17/2017   23:34:30    23:53:15
```

Comment: What attached image? Also I suggest you add line breaks to your data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Ashish, please stop editing back n forth the post!

Comment: @anotherfred: I have edited the post, please have a look and suggest how can this be achieved on R

Comment: @amonk : Thank you for the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will get back what you want.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
df$StartDate=mdy_hms(paste(df$Date,df$Start))
df$EndDate=mdy_hms(paste(df$Date,df$End))
df=df%>%group_by(UserId,Video_id)%>%arrange(StartDate)%>%dplyr::mutate(sessionGap=abs(lag(EndDate)-StartDate))
```

example output:

```
> head(df)
Source: local data frame [6 x 8]
Groups: UserId, Video_id [3]

                                UserId Video_id      Date    Start      End           StartDate             EndDate sessionGap
                                 <chr>    <int>     <chr>    <chr>    <chr>              <dttm>              <dttm>     <time>
1 625fbd55-50bc-40c8-a321-3fc5d6545148   515531 6/17/2017  7:25:27  7:25:39 2017-06-17 07:25:27 2017-06-17 07:25:39    NA secs
2 f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017  9:27:33  9:27:33 2017-06-17 09:27:33 2017-06-17 09:27:33    NA secs
3 f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017  9:34:05  9:46:57 2017-06-17 09:34:05 2017-06-17 09:46:57   392 secs
4 f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017  9:48:17  9:48:24 2017-06-17 09:48:17 2017-06-17 09:48:24    80 secs
5 88A5F59B-2A3F-45C8-8072-7CEF623C59AD   516223 6/17/2017  9:58:44 10:09:54 2017-06-17 09:58:44 2017-06-17 10:09:54    NA secs
6 f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017 10:10:30 10:10:30 2017-06-17 10:10:30 2017-06-17 10:10:30  1326 secs
```

Comment: Thanks  a lot. This works. Extremely happy to have a solution now.

Comment: @amonk: Thanks for understanding, editing and giving the problem a try. I must say I had a great first time experience at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that `dt` is your data.table:

```
library(data.table)# loading necessary packages
library(lubridate)# idem 

dt[,numberOfSession:=.N,by=.(UserId,Video_id)]# count occurrences per user and video id 

dt[,StartDate:=mdy_hms(paste(dt$Date,dt$Start))]# prepare start date
dt[,EndDate:=mdy_hms(paste(dt$Date,dt$End))]# prepare end date
dt[,TimeDiff:=difftime(dt$EndDate,dt$StartDate)]# calculate difference in [sec]
```

resulting in:

```
                                  UserId Video_id      Date    Start      End numberOfSession           StartDate             EndDate  TimeDiff
 1: 88A5F59B-2A3F-45C8-8072-7CEF623C59AD   516223 6/17/2017  9:58:44 10:09:54               1 2017-06-17 09:58:44 2017-06-17 10:09:54  670 secs
 2: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017 10:27:15 10:27:19               6 2017-06-17 10:27:15 2017-06-17 10:27:19    4 secs
 3: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017 10:25:49 10:26:21               6 2017-06-17 10:25:49 2017-06-17 10:26:21   32 secs
 4: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017 10:10:30 10:10:30               6 2017-06-17 10:10:30 2017-06-17 10:10:30    0 secs
 5: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017  9:48:17  9:48:24               6 2017-06-17 09:48:17 2017-06-17 09:48:24    7 secs
 6: bd9299dc-462a-4fde-aed1-ed8cfd9b437f   516221 6/17/2017 17:44:34 17:44:34               1 2017-06-17 17:44:34 2017-06-17 17:44:34    0 secs
 7: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017  9:34:05  9:46:57               6 2017-06-17 09:34:05 2017-06-17 09:46:57  772 secs
 8: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 6/17/2017  9:27:33  9:27:33               6 2017-06-17 09:27:33 2017-06-17 09:27:33    0 secs
 9: 625fbd55-50bc-40c8-a321-3fc5d6545148   515531 6/17/2017  7:25:27  7:25:39               1 2017-06-17 07:25:27 2017-06-17 07:25:39   12 secs
10: 421c6815-9a7c-432c-9f07-2b19d973628c   514625 6/17/2017 20:53:27 20:53:27               1 2017-06-17 20:53:27 2017-06-17 20:53:27    0 secs
11: b3467b1c-f0d1-4330-95ab-d1a6efe88044   487491 6/17/2017 20:25:31 21:08:01               1 2017-06-17 20:25:31 2017-06-17 21:08:01 2550 secs
12: 5155a544-0ee8-4376-ad9f-d839ce691aa7   459908 6/17/2017 16:29:49 16:50:25               1 2017-06-17 16:29:49 2017-06-17 16:50:25 1236 secs
13: 4db1ef03-90f4-4c23-9e73-df3f78f59507   514625 6/17/2017 17:41:03 17:41:03               2 2017-06-17 17:41:03 2017-06-17 17:41:03    0 secs
14: 4db1ef03-90f4-4c23-9e73-df3f78f59507   514625 6/17/2017 17:28:04 17:36:58               2 2017-06-17 17:28:04 2017-06-17 17:36:58  534 secs
15: 3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f   515531 6/17/2017 14:50:47 14:51:28               3 2017-06-17 14:50:47 2017-06-17 14:51:28   41 secs
16: 3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f   515531 6/17/2017 14:47:44 14:47:47               3 2017-06-17 14:47:44 2017-06-17 14:47:47    3 secs
17: 3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f   515531 6/17/2017 14:45:53 14:47:01               3 2017-06-17 14:45:53 2017-06-17 14:47:01   68 secs
18: 43fc3478-d3b0-4f96-a6a1-4e23fa5e075c   515889 6/17/2017 23:47:41 23:49:26               1 2017-06-17 23:47:41 2017-06-17 23:49:26  105 secs
19: b4f442bc-6e15-4757-850f-3d1444be74c5   515461 6/17/2017 23:57:53 23:57:53               1 2017-06-17 23:57:53 2017-06-17 23:57:53    0 secs
20: b4f442bc-6e15-4757-850f-3d1444be74c5   515531 6/17/2017 23:56:33 23:56:33               1 2017-06-17 23:56:33 2017-06-17 23:56:33    0 secs
21: a07898f2-2fba-4406-b3f4-8cc9e9f51ecf   515531 6/17/2017 23:46:37 23:53:45               1 2017-06-17 23:46:37 2017-06-17 23:53:45  428 secs
22: cb222c84-c32c-40f5-9fab-e4ce5be0985e   515889 6/17/2017 23:34:30 23:53:15               1 2017-06-17 23:34:30 2017-06-17 23:53:15 1125 secs
                                  UserId Video_id      Date    Start      End numberOfSession           StartDate             EndDate  TimeDiff
```

As a final step on one can calculate the lag between sessions as follows:

```
dt2<-dt[,.(UserId,Video_id,StartDate,EndDate)]#keep the necessary columns
setkey(dt2, UserId, Video_id,StartDate) #sorting data


dt3<-dt2[,StartDateShift:=shift(StartDate,1),by=.(UserId,Video_id)]#shifting StartDate 
dt3[,TimeLag:=difftime(EndDate,StartDateShift)][!is.na(TimeLag)]

                                UserId Video_id           StartDate             EndDate      StartDateShift        TimeLag
1: 3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f   515531 2017-06-17 14:47:44 2017-06-17 14:47:47 2017-06-17 14:45:53  1.900000 mins
2: 3fe03ef2-dbfd-4312-9e67-6d1ba2a4508f   515531 2017-06-17 14:50:47 2017-06-17 14:51:28 2017-06-17 14:47:44  3.733333 mins
3: 4db1ef03-90f4-4c23-9e73-df3f78f59507   514625 2017-06-17 17:41:03 2017-06-17 17:41:03 2017-06-17 17:28:04 12.983333 mins
4: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 2017-06-17 09:34:05 2017-06-17 09:46:57 2017-06-17 09:27:33 19.400000 mins
5: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 2017-06-17 09:48:17 2017-06-17 09:48:24 2017-06-17 09:34:05 14.316667 mins
6: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 2017-06-17 10:10:30 2017-06-17 10:10:30 2017-06-17 09:48:17 22.216667 mins
7: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 2017-06-17 10:25:49 2017-06-17 10:26:21 2017-06-17 10:10:30 15.850000 mins
8: f243d1cc-783e-4467-9329-4b7a8cfb3a65   516379 2017-06-17 10:27:15 2017-06-17 10:27:19 2017-06-17 10:25:49  1.500000 mins
>
```

Comment: @Thanks amonk. I was able to get the time difference but the solution i want is to get the gap between the the first session and second session, sescond session and 3rd session and so on.

Comment: @Ashish ok hold tight. brb

Comment: @Thanks amonk. I want to get the difference between sessions:                                                                                                                                     In the data if you see row 2 to 5 represents 4 session a user "f243******----a65" had on video id "516379". I want to get the difference between those five sessions. His first session started(row5) at 9:48:17 and ended at 9:48:24 and then the second session started at 10:10:30. So the session gap is of 22minutes. i want this number against the sessions. Obviously the first session would have null entry.

Comment: @Ashish I implemented some changes. Let me know if you need anything else